# Using a list as a function parameter

Tags: python, list, function, parameters

Is it possible to create a function that uses an int and a list as parameters, like this:

```py
def areavsprodcution_per_region(integer, list):
```

I tried to do this:

```py
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    listof_products = listof_products.split()
    for i in range(len(listof_products)):
         listof_products= listof_products[i] 
    return(listof_products)
```

But it isn't working:

```py
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: of course, you can pass whatever you want as method parameter. What do you try to achieve ? Share an example input and the expected output

Comment: You destroy the list, which causes this error. Also your question is strange, because if you were really passing a list as second argument, you will get an error on the `split`, not the error you mention. What is the aim of this function? Can you provide examples on how you call this function and what you expect to get back from it?

Answer (score 0):

I got our problem but when we use .split() method with string it takes an argument that on what basis it is to split the string. If you give any appreciable argument to .split() method then It may not throw any error.

```
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    listof_products = listof_products.split()
    for i in range(len(listof_products)):
         listof_products= listof_products[i] 
    return(listof_products)
```

Change to :

```
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    listof_products = listof_products.split(" ") # either with " " or "," or anything
    for i in range(len(listof_products)):
         listof_products= listof_products[i] 
    return(listof_products)
```

I hope this may help you to get over your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Index in python starts at 0, which you have to account for in looping through your list.
Also, it looks like you're trying to filter here, which isn't being done in your function:

If the list of products has an attribute like a region code, then it'd look more like this:

```py
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    listof_products = listof_products.split()
    for i in range(len(listof_products)-1):
        if listof_products[i].region_code == region_code:
            region_products = listof_products[i]
        else:
            region_products = "Not found"
    return(region_products)
```

if the order of the list is the region code, then you'd want something like this:

```py
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    listof_products = listof_products.split()
    return(listof_products[region_code-1])
```

If you keep the original function, and just account for the items starting at 0, then you'd get this:

```py
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    listof_products = listof_products.split()
    for i in range(len(listof_products)-1):
         listof_products= listof_products[i] 
    return(listof_products)
```

If you're truly getting a list as input, then you shouldn't need to use .split(), meaning you'd get something like these:

If you're getting a dictionary or something similar, i.e.

```
region_code     products
1               product1, product2
2               product3, product4
```

then this:

```
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    for i in range(len(listof_products)-1):
        if listof_products[i].region_code == region_code:
            region_products = listof_products[i].products
        else:
            region_products = "Not found"
    return(region_products)
```

if it's just a position in a list, then this:

```py
def areavsprodcution_per_region(region_code, listof_products):
    return(listof_products[region_code-1])
```